# Grouping Cassandra columns using Solr

Tags: solr, group-by, cassandra

Is it possible to Group By the Cassandra columns using solr?

I have 2 columns

```
ColumnA ColumnB
A         XYZ
B         BCD
C         CDE
D         DEF
A         XYZ
D         DEF
E         XYZ
A         XYZ
```

I want to get the count of ColumnA where ColumnB='XYZ' as below

```
ColumnA   count(*)
A            3
E            1
```

I am able to get total counts

```
select count(*) from table 
where solr_query='{"q" : "columnB:XYZ"}
```

but not sure how to use the below to get Column wise

```
solr_query='{"q" : "columnB:XYZ"},{group=true&group.field=columnA}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using `Facet` query though result will not be in tabular format.

```
select * from table 
where solr_query='{"q" : "columnB:XYZ","facet":{"field":"columnA","mincount":1}}'
```

Result will be something like

```
|facet_fields             |
|-------------------------|
|{"columnA":{"A":3,"E":1}}|
```

Count and limit does not work with facet.
[Search Query Syntax DSE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/siQuerySyntax.html)

Comment: I am getting the below error, if I try with "facet"

Comment: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Field cache is disabled, set the field=application_id to be docValues=true and reindex.  Or if the field cache will not exceed the heap usage, then place useFieldCache=true in the request parameters.
  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Field cache is disabled, set the field=application_id to be docValues=true and reindex.  Or if the field cache will not exceed the heap usage, then place useFieldCache=true in the request parameters.